# Random DeadlineExceeded errors when using Google Classroom API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-classroom

I have an application running on GAE (Python), where a Google Classroom user can import his/her courses (name and list of students). The code is separated into two parts. First I get a list of all courses for that user:

```
directoryauthdecorator = OAuth2Decorator(
approval_prompt='force',
client_id='my_client_id',
client_secret='my_client_secret',
callback_path='/oauth2callback',
scope=[
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters'])

class ClassroomAPI(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @directoryauthdecorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        function=self.request.get('function')   
        auth_http = directoryauthdecorator.http()
        service = build("classroom", "v1", http=auth_http)

        if function == "getAllCourses":
            try:

                 results = service.courses().list(pageSize=100,teacherId=users.get_current_user().email(),courseStates="ACTIVE").execute()
                 courses = results.get('courses',[])

                 #PARSE AND RETURN LIST OF COURSES TO USER
            except errors.HttpError, error:
                 #RETURN ERROR


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                         [('/classroomAPI', ClassroomAPI),
                         (directoryauthdecorator.callback_path, directoryauthdecorator.callback_handler())],
                         debug=True)
```

This part works all the time. The user then selects, which courses he/she wants to import from the list. The selected courses are posted back to the script above and the next part is executed:

```
        if function == "getStudentListForCourse":
            students=[]
            selectedCourses = json.loads(self.request.body)["courses"]
            for course in selectedCourses:
                page_token=None
                while True:
                    params={}
                    params["courseId"]=course["classroomId"]
                    params["pageSize"]=50
                    if page_token:
                        params["pageToken"]=page_token

                    studentList = service.courses().students().list(**params).execute()
                    for student in studentList['students']:
                        students.append(student['profile']['emailAddress'])

                    page_token = studentList.get('nextPageToken')
                    if not page_token:
                        break

            #RETURN STUDENTS
```

The problem here is that my logs keep reporting 'DeadlineExceededError' at random times on line `studentList = service.courses().students().list(**params).execute()` , which makes the importing process unreliable.

Any tips would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I've tried the suggestion posted by alpeware, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the duration of your call, you are hitting the [60sec timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_The_request_timer) imposed on requests. You can't change this timeout as it helps App Engine do it's scaling magic.

To get around the timeout, I'd recommend using a [Push Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/) as part of the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/) service.

You'd have to refactor your code to accommodate asynchronous loading of the student list in your UI and store the list of students in the datastore.

In your specific use case, you could refactor your code to use the [deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) to populate the list of students.

To enable the deferred library, you'll have to make the following changes to your `app.yaml` -

Add the following entry to the `builtins` section of your `app.yaml`:

```
- deferred: on
```

and the following entry to the handlers section of the same file:

```
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
    script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
    login: admin
```

Here's something to get you started refactoring your code to use the deferred library -

```
    from util import getStudentList

    if function == "getStudentListForCourse":
        credentials = directoryauthdecorator.get_credentials()
        selectedCourses = json.loads(self.request.body)["courses"]
        for course in selectedCourses:
            deferred.defer(getStudentList, course, credentials, None, [])
```

Then create a new module `util.py` -

```
     import httplib2
     from google.appengine.api import memcache

     def getStudentList(course=None, credentials=None, pageToken=None, students=None):
        http = httplib2.Http(cache=memcache)
        auth_http = credentials.authorize(http)
        service = build("classroom", "v1", http=auth_http)

        params = {}
        params["courseId"] = course["classroomId"]
        params["pageSize"] = 50
        if pageToken:
            params["pageToken"] = pageToken
        studentList = service.courses().students().list(**params).execute()
        for student in studentList['students']:
            students.append(student['profile']['emailAddress'])

        pageToken = studentList.get('nextPageToken')
        if pageToken:
            return deferred.deferr(getStudentList, course, credentials, pageToken, students)
        # There are no more students for this class.
        # TODO: store students for course
```

As mentioned, you will have to change your views to return results from the datastore when all the tasks have been completed.

Let me know if you have further questions and happy to provide additional pointers.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed post. I'm now wondering what's the best way to handle API authorization in this case. I've implemented your advice, but cannot seem to authorize correctly beyond the first API call. I keep getting error 401 invalid credentials after that.

Comment: No problem! I'm not familiar with the classroom API specifics. How are you creating your service at the moment and what credentials are you passing? If it's on a per user basis, you can include the user_id and retrieve your access token based on that. The official oauth2 client has models specifically for app engine. Let me know and happy to add more details.

Comment: I'm currently using an OAuth2Decorator as shown in the first code snippet in my original post. I pass my app's client id and secret to the constructor.

Comment: *Doh* missed it. I edited the answer to include passing the credentials and constructing the service in the task queue. It should work, but let me know if there's another issue.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, you've been extremely helpful. I will go on and finish the whole implementation and then accept the answer if the errors get solved.

Comment: Awesome and glad to help! Btw, is your project public and do you mind sharing its URL? Always curious to see the various projects people are working on!

Comment: It's part of an app we are developing for schools using GSuite for Education. Unfortunately, currently not publicly available.

Comment: Cool! Let me know if you guys need some help. Details in my profile. Go education!

Comment: Unfortunately the random timeouts remain even after trying your suggested approach. There is no pattern at all it seems. One time it fails even when there's just one course being imported (one API call), other time it goes through for 4 in a row.

Comment: It appears we're just dealing with a flaky service. Task queues are retrying a failed task, so if it's just random flakiness, it should go through eventually without you having to do anything! Of course it would be better to make the service more stable, but if that's outside your control, you will just have to retry. Is that not working properly at the moment?

Comment: One more thought is to experiment with reducing the page size parameter. Try something like 10 and see if that fixes the issue and then gradually increase it again.

Comment: I've tried manipulating pretty much every parameter last week without success. However, the good news in the past couple of days the errors stopped even though I reverted the code to its original form. Looks like there might have really been an issue with their service. We'll see how it goes this week.